Can axial myopia be caused by gravity?
I've been reading up on axial myopia and a few things struck me as odd.
This meta-analysis suggests that spending time outside decreases rates and severities of myopia. This makes me think that whatever is causing myopia might be inside, and after witnessing some school kids working on a test in a classroom, it hit me.
The schools' desk and chair setups around the world are far from ergonomic, so more often than not kids have to tilt their head or bend their bodies to read or write. While doing that, they align the front-back axis of their eyeballs with the vector of Earth's gravity. The acceleration caused by gravity exerts a constant force on the eyes that is normally not present along the front-back axis when we sit or stand upright. Combine the eyes being incredibly soft and prone to deformation more than other tissues with the general developmental stage of children's bodies making any kind of deformation and trauma more likely to be permanent in adult years, and you get a lot of myopic people in countries with high rates of formal education, especially among the most studious of people who are more likely to be bent over a book or writing something, and you get to where we are now.
Is this a new hypothesis or did someone already proposed and disproved it?
If that's the case, we could mitigate this by making reading/writing setups in schools more ergonomic, more like the ones from back in the day when we used quills to write. The one's I've seen have a more upright writing surface that's closer to the eye level so that the ink would flow down the page properly or some such
